# TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have the following textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="content" name="content" required>
        </textarea>
```

and the following submit button:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="content.valid">New comment</button>
```

As I saw in the angular 2 form guide (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) I can use the `x.valid` in order to check if it's not empty.

Why do I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined` error?

Comment: i guess you missed this: '#name="ngModel"'. in your case: #content="ngModel"

Comment: Actually I get the same error

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In your case **content** is a property on your model.

In order to do what you want you need to use a [template reference value](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars) for the form control *#myControl="ngModel"* and then you have access to the valid property: *myControl.valid*.

So in your example:

```
<textarea class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="content"
          name="content" required #myControl="ngModel">
</textarea>
```

And use it in the button tag:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
[disabled]="myControl.valid">New comment</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! How I can send `content` in my `ngSubmit()`? My form is assigned with `<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">` but I have no idea how to get the content value with this way

Comment: If you used ngModel on the controls everything is binded to your model, so you can use that. If you need more from the form you can do as in the doc and get a reference for the form itself '#heroForm="ngForm"' and then use that.

Comment: What I don't understand is how I can use the value of `content` in my component (.ts file)? Do I need to pass it as parameter or I can use it in my component another way?

Comment: Content should be a property in your component starting with. Since it's using two way binding it will have the latest changes when you call submit. Have a look at the end of the docs section on the link you provided, might be easier to understand from them.

Comment: "Everything is binded to your model" helped me out, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this type of validation in reactive form?  and say ` *ngIf="name.errors.required"` show an <input> div?

Comment: @GelSisaed yes, you can do exactly what you suggested. Add the error template with ngIf. If you need to fetch an individual control you can use the form for that `myForm.get('name')?.errors`

Comment: @AdrianFâciu thanks much I will try `myForm.get('name')?.errors` -

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" minlength="4" maxlength="24"  [(ngModel)]="name" name="email" #myName="ngModel" required>
            <div *ngIf="myName.errors && (myName.dirty || myName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div [hidden]="!myName.errors.required">
                    Name is required
                </div>
                <div [hidden]="!myName.errors.minlength">
                    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
                </div>
                <div [hidden]="!myName.errors.maxlength">
                    Name cannot be more than 24 characters long.
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem due to using ng-if. I solved it using ng-hide instead.

ng-hide set DOM visibility false but ng-if removes DOM completely. Probably thats why angularjs can't see the form to validate when ng-if is used

Answer (score 0):

In my case i removed the  ngModel from #myName="ngModel" to make it work.
Angualr version 5.2.11

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ngModelChange` as a workaround:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="model.property (ngModelChange)="detectChanges($event, model, validation)" #validation="ngModel" required validation>
```

And in your component:

```
 detectChanges(newVal, model, validation): void {
     if (validation.valid) model._valid = true;
     else model._valid = false;
 }
```

This can give you more flexibility when you are using `*ngFor` to display lots of input fields and want to validate them individually.