# How to identify which custom validation function is causing error in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have number of validators assigned to a formControl with formControlName as firstName.
How to know which validation is giving error so that I can give appropriate message

Following is my custom made validation function for required

```
export function required() {
  return function(control:FormControl)
  {
    var value: string = control.value;
    value = value.trim();
    if(value.length == 0)
      return {required:true};    
    return null;
  } 
 }
```

and using is like this

```
<md-error [hidden]="!firstName.errors.required || (!firstName.touched && !submitted)">
   Name is required
</md-error>
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of null
```

Comment: Do you haveReactiveFormsModule defined within @ngModule of app-module.ts?  ( from '@angular/forms', imported and in imports: [] array)

Comment: @JGFMK reactive forms are working  only this error part is not working

Comment: @JGFMK didnt do it in app-module instead did it in the module which contains my component

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYv9lsrV0s4&feature=youtu.be&t=1050 https://github.com/kara/ac-forms https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1rufZvQabEwpinabiMRq1rAa5nWR3ZpsTvw4snePAsjM/preview?slide=id.p

Comment: @JGFMK thanks for the reply but they are creating a directive for it , i just want to create a function and add it to validators array in formControl, Validation works for me. But i am not able to get which validation is giving error

Comment: Well also maybe this is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213386/typeerror-cannot-read-property-valid-of-undefined - a template reference variable akin to #myName="ngModel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<md-error *ngIf="firstName.hasError('required') && (firstName.touched || submitted)">
   Please enter the required field
</md-error>
```

this worked for me.

firstName.errors.required  doesnt work

thank you for all the help.

if there are multiple validation fails and multiple messages then u can show only the first error message by adding in css

```
md-error:not(:first-of-type) { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Template Driven Form** Approach mentioned required inside your input tag.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" #nameRef="ngModel" ngModel required name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
```

Or In case of **Reactive Form** approach

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      name:[[],[<any>Validators.required]],
   })
```

Comment: i dont want to use libraby validators , i want to use custom validators,  required is just an example

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your `errors` may be null so you should use an elvis or safe navigation operator: `?.` like this:

```html
<md-error [hidden]="!firstName.errors?.required || (!firstName.touched && !submitted)">
   Name is required
</md-error>
```

You mentioned in the comments:

> i dont want to use libraby validators , i want to use custom validators, required is just an example

If you are not going to use the [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) approach mentioned in [Jverma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45475942/6894075) you will need to create a [Directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) as described in [this blog post](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-template-driven-form-validators/) (Relevant code pasted below)

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

// validation function
function validateJuriNameFactory() : ValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl) => {

    let isValid = c.value === 'Juri';

    if(isValid) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return {
            juriName: {
                valid: false
            }
        };
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[juriName][ngModel]'
})
export class JuriNameValidator implements Validator {
  validator: ValidatorFn;

  constructor() {
    this.validator = validateJuriNameFactory();
  }

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validator(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: u can directly make a function and export it, include int hte file and use it . Directives is also a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional information to the error object returned by the validator:

```
export function required(String info) {
  return function(control:FormControl)
  {
    var value: string = control.value;
    value = value.trim();
    if(value.length == 0)
      return {required:true, info: info};    
    return null;
  } 
 }
```

```
his.userForm = this.fb.group({
  name:[[],[<any>required('firstName')]],
})
```

```
<md-error [hidden]="!firstName.errors.required || (!firstName.touched && !submitted)">
   <div *ngFor="let err of firstName.errors">
     {{error?.info}}
   </div>
</md-error>
```

Comment: i dont knwo why firstName.errors.required doesnt work for my but firstName.hasError('required') worked

Comment: I guess `firstName.errors` is a list, not an object. I think it's not supposed to work. I missed to look closer at this part of your question.