# Angular 4 Reset Form Values in HTML

Tags: html, forms, angular, typescript

I have the following From in my HTML component:

```
<form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantName.valid }">
        <label for="powerPlantName">PowerPlant Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantName" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantName" #powerPlantName="ngModel" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantType.valid }">
        <label for="powerPlantType">PowerPlant Type</label>
        <select class="hideLabel form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType" (change)="selectName();">
          <option selected="" value="">--Select Type--</option>
          <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
            {{ powerPlantType }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !organizationName.valid }">
        <label for="organizationName">Organization Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantOrganization" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantOrganization" #organizationName="ngModel" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantStatus.valid }">
        <label for="powerPlantStatus">PowerPlant Active Status</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantStatus" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantStatus" #powerPlantStatus="ngModel" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-4">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Search For PowerPant's...</button>
        <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reset(f)">Reset Search Criteria</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

The corresponding Typescript is as below:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // Represents the PowerPlantTypes
  powerPlantTypes = ['RampUpType', 'OnOffType'];
  // Represents the search form
  model: any = {};
  // currentUser: User;
  // represents the list of PowerPlant data
  powerPlants: PowerPlant[];
  users: User[] = [];

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private powerPlantService: PowerPlantService) {
    // this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allPowerPlants();
  }

  selectName() {
    alert(this.model.powerPlantType);
  }

  searchPowerPlants(): void {
    const powerPlantSearchParams = new PowerPlantSearchParams(
      this.model.powerPlantType,
      this.model.powerPlantOrganization,
      this.model.powerPlantName,
      this.model.page,
      this.model.powerPlantStatus);

    this.powerPlantService.searchPowerPlants(powerPlantSearchParams).subscribe(result => {
      this.powerPlants = <PowerPlant[]> result;
    });
  }

  allPowerPlants(onlyActive: boolean = false, page: number = 1): void {
    this.powerPlantService.allPowerPlants(onlyActive, page).subscribe(result => {
      this.powerPlants = <PowerPlant[]> result;
    });
  }
}
```

When I tried resetting the form using the reset button, I see hell lot of errors in my console. One such error looks like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at Object.View_HomeComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13065)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12245)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12542)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12251)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12568)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12246)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
```

So line number 11 in HomeComponent.html is this one:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantName" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantName" #powerPlantName="ngModel" />
```

What is wrong here? This is a common problem that many of you might faced! Could anyone please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's just a guess but I see in this ["not totally unrelated post"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39213598/5234260) that `valid` is a direct prop of the template ref.

So, in your use case, I would tried to:

```
remove  <form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
add     <form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.valid && searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
```

Comment: Ok, and adding `[formControl]='foo'` in the input and then using `foo.reset()` in the click event ?

Comment: I have posted a solution that got rid of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
    <form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.valid && searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
        <label for="powerPlantName">PowerPlant Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control-small" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantName.valid }" name="powerPlantName" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantName" #powerPlantName="ngModel" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
        <label for="powerPlantType">PowerPlant Type</label>
        <select class="hideLabel form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType" (change)="selectName();">
          <option value="" disabled value="0">--Select Type--</option>
          <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
            {{ powerPlantType }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
        <label for="organizationName">Organization Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantOrganization" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantOrg" #organizationName="ngModel" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
        <label for="powerPlantStatus">PowerPlant Active Status</label>
        <select class="hideLabel form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantStatus" name="powerPlantStatus" (change)="selectName();">
          <option value="" disabled value="0" >--Select Status--</option>
          <option [ngValue]="powerPlantStatus" *ngFor="let powerPlantStatus of powerPlantStatuses">
            {{ powerPlantStatus }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-4">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Search For PowerPant's...</button>
        <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAP///wAAAMLCwkJCQgAAAGJiYoKCgpKSkiH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh/hpDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggYWpheGxvYWQuaW5mbwAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMwi63P4wyklrE2MIOggZnAdOmGYJRbExwroUmcG2LmDEwnHQLVsYOd2mBzkYDAdKa+dIAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADNAi63P5OjCEgG4QMu7DmikRxQlFUYDEZIGBMRVsaqHwctXXf7WEYB4Ag1xjihkMZsiUkKhIAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzYIujIjK8pByJDMlFYvBoVjHA70GU7xSUJhmKtwHPAKzLO9HMaoKwJZ7Rf8AYPDDzKpZBqfvwQAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzMIumIlK8oyhpHsnFZfhYumCYUhDAQxRIdhHBGqRoKw0R8DYlJd8z0fMDgsGo/IpHI5TAAAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzIIunInK0rnZBTwGPNMgQwmdsNgXGJUlIWEuR5oWUIpz8pAEAMe6TwfwyYsGo/IpFKSAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMwi6IMKQORfjdOe82p4wGccc4CEuQradylesojEMBgsUc2G7sDX3lQGBMLAJibufbSlKAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMgi63P7wCRHZnFVdmgHu2nFwlWCI3WGc3TSWhUFGxTAUkGCbtgENBMJAEJsxgMLWzpEAACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAAQABAAAAMyCLrc/jDKSatlQtScKdceCAjDII7HcQ4EMTCpyrCuUBjCYRgHVtqlAiB1YhiCnlsRkAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA==" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="f.reset()">Reset Search Criteria</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I had to move the [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantName.valid }" from the div into the input html tag!